# C++ macro parsing issue

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to use a macro to queue up a single log line locally in an ostringstream and then dump the entire contents of that ostringstream when the line is over. I want to still use stream insert syntax, however.  So I want to turn a log line like this:

```
std::cerr << "Some error in my function.  Code is " << errCode << " exiting" << std::endl;
```

...into this

```
SERR("Some error in my function.  Code is " << errCode << " exiting);
```

I've got something simple that works well.  That is, until I put it in an if-else statement.  Obviously my macro is bad but I am at a loss as to what to do.

Here is a small sample program, hacked up to illustrate the problem.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#define SERR(x)     { std::ostringstream _s; ; _s << x << std::endl; std::cerr << _s.str(); }

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    bool val = false;
    if (val)
        SERR("No error");
    else
        SERR("Error"); 
}
```

The error message I get from the compiler in this sample is:

> 1>c:\users\joe\source\repos\consoleapplication5\consoleapplication5\consoleapplication5.cpp(15):
>   error C2181: illegal else without matching if

Any ideas what I've got wrong here?

(Note I'm not in a place where I can use a 3rd Party logging solution now so it's got to be something simple like this.  I could just leave all this as normal `std::cerr`/`std::cout`/`std::clog` messages, if I had to but I'd prefer something simple to minimize the chances of interleaving of log messages from my multithreaded app.)

Comment: It's generally a good idea to separate responsibilities. A general `<<` facility for function arguments instead of something hardwired for just log messages, would IMO be much nicer. E.g. with (https://github.com/alf-p-steinbach/cppx/blob/master/source/text/To_str_.hpp) you can write function calls like `foo( To_str() << "2*pi = " << 2*3.14 )`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try to expand it and see what you get:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    bool val = false;
    if (val)
        { std::ostringstream _s; ; _s << "No error" << std::endl; std::cerr << _s.str(); };
    else
        { std::ostringstream _s; ; _s << "Error" << std::endl; std::cerr << _s.str(); };
}
```

Notice how `{ }` block is terminated with `;`?

If you need a macro, you should always write it using `do { } while (0)` like this:

```
#define SERR(x)                                     \
    do {                                            \
        std::ostringstream _s;                      \
        _s << (x) << std::endl;                     \
        std::cerr << _s.str();                      \
    } while (0)
```

Not only this solves your issue, but also make it mandatory to add `;` after the macro. Otherwise people could use it two ways:

```
SERR("foo")  // without ;
...
SERR("bar"); // with ;
```

Comment: So *that's* why I see so many macros like that (with the do-while syntax).  I had never made the connection.  Thank you.  Been programming C++ forever but I've always been terrible in this area

Comment: @Joe Also it is recommended wrapping arguments in parenthesis like this `(x)`.